# How to use Node.js MongoDB Driver API ChangeStream class method hasNext(callback)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, changestream

I am new to Node.js, and try to use Node.js Mongodb drive API changeStream (https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/ChangeStream.html#hasNext). I do not know how to deal with Nodejs return Promise. My code is as below.

```
change_stream.hasNext().then(function(){
    const change = change_stream.next();
    console.log(change)
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
});
```

The output is:
    Promise {  }

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Here's a [usefull link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that explains promises

Comment: Thanks! It is helpful. The reason is that change_stream.next() also returns Promise, so I need take care also.